# Can't push view controller from UISearchDisplayController delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have created a UISearchDisplayController which uses a separate UITableViewController as the delegate to display the results of the search. In this view controller, I have the 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' method which allocates and initializes a detailViewController then uses:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController: detailViewController animated: YES];
```

to push it onto the stack. However, this line doesn't work. When a cell is tapped, nothing happens. 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' is being called, but the 'pushViewController' method call isn't working. Am I not in the context of my navigationController any more? How can I fix this problem?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like [self navigationController] is nil. Make a breakpoint in the code and see if it is indeed nil. If it is nil then you need to find which view controller is actually inside the navigation controller and call it there.

Comment: I was having this issue with the new UISearchController and this helped me solved it: https://twitter.com/marcoarment/status/506609645335904257, had to have self.definesPresentationContext = true in the main view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your table's navigationController is probably the wrong one, I think that you might want to push it on the navigationController of your UISearchDisplayController.
To do this, you can create a protocol in your tableviewcontroller with a method "pushViewController" for instance and have UISearchDisplayController implement it.

Then your register this delegate in your table view and you call your delegate on pushViewcontroller in your 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath'